# Static fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two static fragments in same activity, in "fragmentA" i have a customized list, when an item is clicked must to appear a detail in "fragmentB", detail appear only when i change screen orientation, no automatically. I use this code in main activity for refresh but application restart(detail appear).

finish();
startActivity(getIntent());

Someone knows a better way to make appear detail automatically in "fragmentB" when i clicked some item from "fragmentA", always using two static fragments in same activity.

Comment: I suggest you start by using Android Studio to create a new project, and when it asks you to "Add an activity", choose "Master/Detail Flow". That'll generate some sample code that does what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use static references to hold a `Fragment`, it's a really bad practice.
Don't store the Context in a static reference. [Or you could will leak memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774075/is-it-bad-practice-to-keep-data-in-static-variables).

Instead, implement an `Interface`:

//FragmentActivityTest

```
public class FragmentActivityTest extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
    FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
    fragmentA.setFragmentBHandler(fragmentB);

    //Perform transactions etc
}
}
```

//FragmentA

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

private FragmentBHandler _handler;

public void setFragmentBHandler(FragmentBHandler handler) {
    _handler = handler;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ((ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list_view)).setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            _handler.updateDetail();
        }
    });
}
}
```

//FragmentB

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment implements FragmentBHandler {

@Override
public void updateDetail() {
    //do your work
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an event bus like [greenrobot](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or [otto](http://square.github.io/otto/). `FragmentB` subscribe to an event, and `FragmentA` post that event. When you click on an item, you'll send an event, and the subscriber will execute your action (show details).

Answer (score 0):

Without showing code, I can only guess your current implementation.

The proper way to communicate between fragments is

1. Pass data to the parent activity from Fragment A on item click,
2. Activity passes this data to fragment B by finding the fragment in fragment manager and call a method in fragment B,
3. That method in fragment B should determine if it should populate the detail.