# Static variables, pattern and Android performance

Tags: java, android, performance, static, singleton

I'm doing some big refactoring operations relative to some performance improvements in an android app which is using a class with lot of static variables and even static activity references which are then use through the app ! So I was looking for some best practices in Android to store data and give to these data a global access in my app.

First I removed all the activity references to avoid any memory leak, but I'm still looking to know what is the best practice regarding static variables which need to be used anywhere in the android app.

I read many times ([example1](http://gbracha.blogspot.co.uk/2008/02/cutting-out-static.html), [exemple2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774075/is-it-bad-practice-to-keep-data-in-static-variables/19774331#19774331)) : using static variables is not necessary a good practices and it's better/cleaner to use one singleton class with getter and setter to have access to my global variables whatever the activity where I am. So what I've started to think is a class which could looks like this one :

```
public class AppSingleton extends Application {

    private static AppSingleton appInstance;

    // different stored data, which could be relative to some settings ..
    private String setting1;
    private String setting2;

    private AppSingleton() {
        super();
        appInstance = new AppSingleton();
    }

    public static  AppSingleton getAppInstance() {
        if (appInstance == null) {
            appInstance = new AppSingleton();
        }
        return appInstance;
    }

    // Getter and Setter for global access
    public String getSetting1() {return setting1;}
    public void setSetting1(String setting1) {this.setting1 = setting1;}

    public String getSetting2() {return setting2;}
    public void setSetting2(String setting2) {this.setting2 = setting2;}
}
```

Then I can use for [example](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/#comments) :

```
// Get the application instance
AppSingleton appS = (App) getApplication();

// Call a custom application method
appS.customAppMethod();

// Call a custom method in my App singleton
AppSingleton.getInstance().customAppSingletonMethod();

// Read the value of a variable in my App singleton
String var = AppSingleton.getInstance().getCustomVariable;
```

For me AppSingleton sounds good because this singleton which restrics ths instantiation of this class to one object, also this class is not destroyed until there are any undestroyed Activity in the application so it means I can keep my global data in the current lifecycle of my app for example from a 'Log in'. But also I can maintain the state of my global variables from my getters/setters.

But then I also had a look on the official android documentation about [Performance Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#PreferStatic) which say it's good to use static variable it's faster and don't forget to avoid internal getter and setter it's too expansive !

I'm a bit confused about all of these and I'm really keen to learn more about that topic. What is the best practices about using one class to provide an access to some variables which are needed in different part of my code ? Is the class above AppSingeleton is something which could be interesting to use in terms of architecture and performance ?
Is it a good idea to use a singleton pattern for managing global variables in android ?

Comment: If this may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774075/is-it-bad-practice-to-keep-data-in-static-variables/19774331#19774331

Comment: @Nitesh thanks for this, I've already linked this to my question it's actually helpful but when I read the android Performance Tips I'm also a bit confused..

Comment: My Bad that I again posted the same link :)..even I am excited to know this question's answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those lines are completely wrong on your code:

```
   private AppSingleton() {
        super();
        appInstance = new AppSingleton();
    }

    public static  AppSingleton getAppInstance() {
        if (appInstance == null) {
            appInstance = new AppSingleton();
        }
        return appInstance;
    }
```

you cannot instantiate new `Application`, the Android framework instantiates it. Change to this:

```
   private AppSingleton() {
        super();
        appInstance = this; // keep ref to this application instance
    }

    public static  AppSingleton getAppInstance() {
        return appInstance;
    }
```

Regarding the accessing of global variables. I believe it's more organized to have those singletons somewhere else on your application. The application class have different responsibilities you should not overload it with different tasks. That's OO clean coding.

Also, sometimes there's not that much reason in an Android app to have getters/setters for everything, because u don't need as much access control as in bigger projects. But this should be considered case-by-case about the necessity and not be used a general rule.

So you could for example have it like:

```
public class Globals {
    private static final Globals instance = new Globals();
    public static Globals get() { return instance; }

    public String value1 = "Hello"
    public int value2 = 42;
}
```

then on your code call as needed:

```
Log.d(TAG, Globals.get().value1);
Globals.get().value1 = "World";
Log.d(TAG, Globals.get().value1);
Log.d(TAG, "Value2 = " + Globals.get().value2);
```