# How can I fix android button in Android Studio, throwing cast exception?

Tags: android, button, casting

My app was working fine until I started to click one specific button, the `rate-button`. Every time I click this button, the app crashes and I get this message in log cat:

```
22808/com.nileworx.guesstheplace E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.nileworx.guesstheplace, PID: 22808
                                                                        java.lang.ClassCastException: com.nileworx.guesstheplace.GameActivity cannot be cast to com.nileworx.guesstheplace.MainActivity
                                                                            at com.nileworx.guesstheplace.CustomDialog$11.onClick(CustomDialog.java:283)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-25 06:46:03.423 1642-2032/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.nileworx.guesstheplace/.GameActivity
```

I believe there is a problem in the `gameactivity`, and there is just one error:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (!mSharedPreferences.getString("placesNum", "0").equals("0")) {
        String updatesDlgMsg = String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.updatesDlg), mSharedPreferences.getString("placesNum", "0"));
        dialog.showDialog(R.layout.blue_dialog, "updatesDlg", updatesDlgMsg, mSharedPreferences.getString("placesJSON", ""));
        e.putString("placesNum", "0");
        e.commit();
    }
}
```

**The 6th line of code, has the problem with the following message:**

> Format string 'updatesDlg' is not a valid format string so it should
>   not be passed to String.format less... (Ctrl+F1)  If a string contains
>   a '%' character, then the string may be a formatting string which will
>   be passed to String.format from Java code to replace each '%'
>   occurrence with specific values.  This lint warning checks for two
>   related problems: (1) Formatting strings that are invalid, meaning
>   that String.format will throw exceptions at runtime when attempting to
>   use the format string. (2) Strings containing '%' that are not
>   formatting strings getting passed to a String.format call. In this
>   case the '%' will need to be escaped as '%%'.  NOTE: Not all Strings
>   which look like formatting strings are intended for use by
>   String.format; for example, they may contain date formats intended for
>   android.text.format.Time#format(). Lint cannot always figure out that
>   a String is a date format, so you may get false warnings in those
>   scenarios. See the suppress help topic for information on how to
>   suppress errors in that case

I do not know how to fix this, and I have tried for over 2 hours to solve it.

**My Rate Button Code**

```
private void rateDlg(final Dialog dialog, final String marketLink) {

    Button rateBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rateBtn);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    rateBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sou.playSound(R.raw.buttons);
            dialog.dismiss();
            MainActivity mainAct = (MainActivity) context;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);



            intent.setData(Uri.parse("playstorelink, changed for stackoverflow"));

            if (!mainAct.MyStartActivity(intent)) {
                // Market (Google play) app seems not
                // installed, let's try
                // to open a webbrowser
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("playstorelink, changed for stackoverflow"));
                if (!mainAct.MyStartActivity(intent)) {
                    // Well if this also fails, we have run
                    // out of options,
                    // inform the user.
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Could not open Android market, please install the market app.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    editor.putInt("usingNum", 100);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            } else {
                editor.putInt("usingNum", 100);
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    });

    Button laterBtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.laterBtn);
    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
    laterBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sou.playSound(R.raw.buttons);
            editor.putInt("usingNum", 0);
            editor.commit();
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should post the code for the `rateButton`.

Comment: That is the message I get, when I scroll over the 6th line of code of the 2nd code

Comment: Please do not close the question, In SO a question with a valid answer is consider good for the community since this may help another person. Please accept the answer if it resolved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of closing the question, either accept my answer if it helped solve your problem or leave it open as a resource for others...

Answer (score 2):

First check that `R.string.updatesDlg` exists in your Strings resource file.

Your other issue is due to a bad cast as stated by the error `GameActivity cannot be cast to com.nileworx.guesstheplace.MainActivity`, you are attempting to cast one class to another. Your button dialog code shows that here...

```
MainActivity mainAct = (MainActivity) context;
```

I'm pretty sure `context` in this case is not of type `MainActivity`. Check the type of `context`. The error says it's of type `GameActivity`.

With that said, I don't see why you need to reach out to the `MainActivity`, unless something special happens there. You can create a `Helper` class and include a method that will check if a package is installed. You pass in the context of your activity. Like this:

```
//MainActivity mainAct = (MainActivity) context;
//Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//intent.setData(Uri.parse("playstorelink, changed for stackoverflow"));

if (!isPackageInstalled(playstorelink)) {
    // Market (Google play) app seems not
    // installed, let's try
    // to open a webbrowser
    //intent.setData(Uri.parse("playstorelink, changed for stackoverflow"));
    if (!isPackageInstalled(playstorelink)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Could not open Android market, please install the market app.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        editor.putInt("usingNum", 100);
        editor.commit();
    }
} else {
    editor.putInt("usingNum", 100);
    editor.commit();
}

private boolean isPackageInstalled(Context context, String packagename) {
    try {
        context.packageManager.getPackageInfo(packagename, 0);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

On a side note, this line of code leads me to believe you have your activity's instance saved to a static variable:

`if (!mainAct.MyStartActivity(intent)) {`

This is very bad! I will quote from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19774075/is-it-bad-practice-to-keep-data-in-static-variables) -

> Don't store the Context in a hard reference, ever. Or you will leak
>   memory. An activity has references to View and a multitude of other
>   things. If you store the Context, you're storing the activity and
>   things go bad from there. Learn to pass the Context around, use the
>   Application Context whenever possible and if you need to pass it
>   around, do it for very good reasons. Most of the time the App context
>   is enough for getting resources, strings, etc. If you're going to
>   store the Context, always store context.getApplicationContext(); Never
>   store a static activity context. You can google this too and
>   StackOverflow has some good answers.

Instead of storing context in a static variable, you can use an event system library such as [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/) to communicate between activities/fragments. You can also just pass the context from one place to another or use an intent `putExtras` to add data to the intent and then receive it in another activity/dialog...

Comment: Okay, so how can I change the last thing, so context and mainactivity are the same type? I am not that good in working with Android Studio.

Comment: What is `mainAct`, is it something like this `public static MainActivity mainAct;`?

Comment: What is the type of that `context` variable? if you can post the whole activity *replacing the code you posted for button*

Comment: Yes it is actually

Comment: @Raven then my updated answer will help you, it is VERY bad to do that. I know because I did the same thing when I got started with Android. Never store activity references, context or anything of the sort in static variables. I will update my answer with a recommendation.

Comment: @Raven I updated my answer with a change in your code, I see you are just checking if GooglePlay is installed with that method from your MainAct - `MyStartActivity`. You don't need to reach out to another activity for this. You can also launch activities from within this activity with `context.startActivity()`.